# Installing and using cutom certificate for Wcf service hosted in windows to enable SSL(HTTPS)

Tags: wcf

I have WCf service hosted in windows service.
I would want to know how would i make service accessible only through SSL and use certificate provided by certificate issuer(Godaddy,verisign etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you created a WCF-Service you'll be forced to use an Windows IIS Server to host your application. When using an IIS, you can specify the Port and an SSL-Certificate.

To do this, just

- add a new Website to your IIS. Make sure, you are using an application pool that supports `.NET Framework 4.0`.
- copy your compiled WCF-Service and all references/files that your services needs to the associated IIS-Site-Folder
- Configure the `Bindings` of this IIS Page. You need an imported SSL-Certificate at this point. If you already imported it, you can choose it from a ListBox within the `Bindings`-Dialog.
- Within that dialog, you can specify the port
- Make sure you've opened that port on your firewall

If you delete other bindings (meaning all HTTP Bindings), you can make sure that your service is only reachable through SSL and your specific port.

If you need cheap, good and multidomain/wildcard certificates, please check out [StartSSL](http://startssl.com). In *my* opinion, they serve you the best.

You can find more information about IIS Configuration [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069/en-us).

Comment: My Wcf service is hosted on windows service and i don't intend to host it on IIS so please let me know how do i install certificates to enable SSL for WCF service hosted on windows service